# Bitwise negation up to the first positive bit

Tags: labview

I was working in a project and I can´t use the bitwise negation with a U32 bits (Unsigned 32 bits) because when I tried to use the negation operator for example I have 1 and the negation (according to this function) was the biggest number possible with U32 and I expected the zero. My idea was working with a binary number like (110010) and I need to only negate the bits after the first 1-bit(001101). There is a way to do that in LabVIEW?

Comment: a binary number like `'110010'` as an unsigned 32-bit integer is actually like `'00000000 00000000 00000000 00011010'`. And bit-wise negation does what its designed to do... it will "flip" all of those leading 0s to leading 1s. Seems like you want a different operation, something other than bitwise negation.

Comment: The conversion operation described (to convert 50 to 13, and to convert 1 to 0), would also (presumably) convert 0 to 0. This conversion results in multiple values converted to the same value (i.e. it's not reversible). Values of 0,1,3,7,15,31,... would all convert to `0`. and values of 2,6,10,14,... would all convert to `1`.  and values of 5,13,29,... would all convert to 2.

Comment: @spencer7593 your comment reads like the answer. I encourage you to convert it to an answer.

Comment: @srm:  I don't have an answer for the question that was asked, i.e. "is there a way to ... [derive] the real negation number ... in LabVIEW?"  (my guess is that there is not a builtin in function that does that; and my guess is that there's probably a way to write such a function).  My comment addresses some fundamentally different questions... specifications for the desired function, and why we would need such a function, what would it be useful/used for.

Comment: @spencer7593 Good point. I provided the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This computes the value you are looking for.

- 1110 --> 0001 (aka, 1)
- 1010 --> 0101 (aka, 101)
- 111 --> 000 (aka, 0) [indeed, all patterns that are all "1" will become 0]
- 0 --> 0 [because there are no bits to negate... maybe you want to special case this as "1"?)

**Note:** This is a VI Snippet. Save the .png file to your disk then drag the image from your OS into LabVIEW and it will generate the block diagram (I wrote it in LV 2016, so it works for 2016 or later). Sometimes dragging directly from browser to diagram works, but most browsers seem to strip out the EXIF data that makes that work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution without a loop. It formats the input into its string representation (without leading zeros) to figure out how many bits to negate - call this `n` - and then XOR's the input with `2^n - 1`.

Note that this version will return an output of `1` for an input of `0`.

Using the string functions feels a bit hacky... but it doesn't use a loop!!

[image: solution VI snippet]

Obviously we could instead try to get the 'bit length' of the input using its base-2 log, but I haven't sat down and worked out how to correctly ensure that there are no rounding issues when the input has only its most significant bit set, and therefore the base-2 log should be exactly an integer, but might come out a fraction smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without strings/loops using the conversion to float (a common method of computing `floor(log_2(x))`). This won't work on unsigned types.

[image]